# How can I preselect rows in my React table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm trying to preselect rows in my table but the table won't refresh unless there are changes to the actual data itself. Is there a method to reinit the table that doesn't involve changing the data?

It's also completely possible that my method for approaching this requirement is wrong and there may be a better way? I've created an example sandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mock-preselected-rows-data-t36nl?file=/src/App.js

In this you can see I have a mock response from my server for determining what rows should be selected. I'm then grabbing the data to compare to see if any of the items from the mock response exist in the data and if so push them to a new obj which is then fed into the intialState for selectedRowIds

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your work is all working. The short answer to your question.

As long as you want the user see something, in a *React* way, it needs to be contained in a state, or state derivative. In your case, it's a cell data wrapped in row and in a table.

So you can't avoid selecting it without touching  the data. Unless you don't want user see the change.

Although the checkbox doesn't seem to be part of the original data stream, when you develop on it, you have to make it part of the data. To be honest, it's easy you make it part of the data, because by the time you want to refresh the table, ex. selecting or de-selecting, or deleting a row, you want everything refreshed. Unfortunately it's very difficult to do local refresh with a table in *React*. It's possible, but very difficult, because most of  the design is based on either `prop` or `context`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The bottom item in the table should be selected on first load. You can see it console log out that it should be also, but without updating the data the table won't reinit and show it as selected. However, no data is actually changing so this seems a bit mute and non performant to force a data change (if memo even would update tbh with no changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can also refactor your `handleSelectedRows` function.

```
// Find row ids and compare them with our 'preSelectedTheseItems' array.
  const handleSelectedRows = () => {
     const preIds = preSelectTheseItems.map(item => item.collectibleId)
     return data?.filter((collectibleRow, index) => preIds.includes(collectibleRow.collectibleId));
  };
```

Example : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mock-preselected-rows-data-forked-8hwe6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you - I can see it has selected an item, but it's selecting the first item instead of the last item which has the matching collectibleId? Progress though! Thank you.